# How can I get version of react-native at runtime?

Tags: react-native

The API of React Native is changing fast, as a module developer, I have to do some adaptive work for better compatibility.

How can I do something like that in a RN module (js/objc/java):

```
if (RN_VERSION === ENV.RN_0_11) {
  callNewApi(xxx);
} else {
  callOldApi(xxx);
}
```

Comment: There's currently no way to do this at runtime. Can you leverage package.json to declare that your module depends on a specific version of React Native, and update that when you release a new version of your module?
There will be less breaking changes in the APIs over time.

Comment: I think it's ok for this very beginning stage of RN, but we may have to support a range of stable RN versions in the future.

Comment: This is my answer:
[how-to-get-react-native-version-from-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849770/how-to-get-react-native-version-from-javascript)