# How to get react native version from JavaScript?

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to get react-native`s version through javascript code?
Something like this

```
import {
    Platform
} from 'react-native';
let version = Platform.version;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These code can do the trick.

```
const PACKAGE = require('YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/react-native/package.json');
const version = PACKAGE.version;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to do the same thing.

```
const ReactNativeVersion = require('./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactNativeVersion');
console.log(ReactNativeVersion.version.major + ReactNativeVersion.version.minor);
```